# Silverstripe: Many to many accessible as a sub url on a Page?

Tags: silverstripe

I am struggling with a problem. I've got a sitetree, in which I - obviously - have pages. These pages are of a type that has a many-to-many relationship to a dataobject. Now I would like to achieve something like this:

/Page/DataObject-slug

So, when the system detects that there is an additional "layer" in the url, it should pass that to a predefined function within the Page controller.

Can I use $allowed_actions for that, or would it interfere with the default routings? Also it should be able to use a wildcard, as I don't know the DataObject-slug in advance. If that's not possible, are there any other known ways to achieve this or something similar?

As an alternative, I probably could do something like /Page/SomeAction/DataObject, but that would be really ugly, and probably not acceptable for the customer.

Another option would of course be using controllers as pages, but that would remove the possibility to nest Pages easily for the user, and create a structure like /ParentPage/Page/DataObject-slug.

I am using SS 3.1.6

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used https://github.com/NightJar/ssrigging-slug for this. It shouldn't matter if your relation is a has_many or many_many, you can access the items in your controller with `$this->ManyManyRelationName()`

It utilizes `$url_handlers` for this job.

If you have any problems installing it please provide a paste of your code.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So private static $extensions = array('Extension_name') is the way to couple an extension to a specific class outside of the yaml. Never knew that (and it's not really documented either). I'll check if I can get it to work.

Comment: I don't get it to work. When trying a url that should be available, based on the title, it redirects to the homepage. When I create a function that matches the url that should work (as a test), it says "Action 'viewItem' isn't allowed on class ItemsPage_Controller." Any clue?

Comment: Guess you have to add your Action "viewItem" to your ItemPage_Controller `$allowed_actions` array